# friend declaration in C++

Tags: c++, declaration, friend

In Thinking in C++ by Bruce eckel, there is an example given regarding friend functions as

```
// Declaration (incomplete type specification):
struct X;
struct Y {
void f(X*);
};
struct X { // Definition
private:
int i;
public:
friend void Y::f(X*); // Struct member friend
};
void Y::f(X* x) {
x->i = 47;
}
```

Now he explained this:

> Notice that Y::f(X*) takes the address of an X
>   object. This is critical because the compiler always knows how to
>   pass an address, which is of a fixed size regardless of the object
>   being passed, even if it doesn’t have full information about the size
>   of the type. If you try to pass the whole object, however, the
>   compiler must see the entire structure definition of X, to know the
>   size and how to pass it, before it allows you to declare a function
>   such as Y::g(X).

But when I tried

```
void f(X);
```

as declaration in struct Y, it shows no error.
Please explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter types for function *declarations* may be incomplete.

For data member declarations and all *definitions* however, the type has to be complete:

```
struct A;
struct B {
    void f(A);   // declaration, fine
    void g(A) {} // error
    A a;         // error
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be fine to pass the incomplete object `X` by value, though during the function implementation the complete type `X` must be available irrespective of whether the object of type `X` is actually used in function or not.
 A function declaration is all fine with incomplete object as argument or return type, except covariant return type (for member function) where such return type must be complete type.

Comment: Thanks, but the last line of his explanation suggests that we can't even declare as void f(X);

Comment: Only during the function definition, the compiler need to know size of object of type X, when X is passed by value, so that it can set up local stack irrespective of whether such value is in use or not. While for a reference or pointer type size of pointer/reference is known to compiler, and hence there is no problem implementing such function as long as any member of the object x is not accessed. If one need to access members of x, complete type of X need to be available. Probably the book wanted to say that as X is incomplete type,in place implementation of f(X*) as given is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

The problems is when you change the declaration in struct X.

So, inside struct X you tell the compiler the struct has a function which receives something of type X, but wait a minute, type X is not fully define at this point!

You can't use an incomplete type as a parameter for function f but you can use the address of an incomplete type, thus X*.

Comment: Yes, that I understand that we can't use an incomplete type as parameter for function but when I declare function in struct Y as
void f(X);
and in struct X, I write
friend void Y::f(X);
then there is no error.
How it is allowed?